# Java: Calender timezone Issue

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
public class **Timezone** {
    private static final String ISO8601_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws ParseException {
        String dt = "2020-09-15 8:56";  // Start date
int offset = -28800;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO8601_FORMAT);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
        c.add(Calendar.SECOND,  -offset);
        dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        System.out.println(dt);
        **TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore");**

        c.setTimeZone(tz);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Output :

--  2020-09-15 16:56
--  2020-09-15 16:56

**My expected output, should be changed time, after timezone change**

Comment: Well you had the wrong expectations, it doesn't work that way. Is there a reason you're using the outdated Calendar API and not the modern `java.time` package?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, how we can do that with time api

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `ZoneId`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: As an aside `2020-09-15 8:56` is not in ISO 8601 format. According to that standard it would be `2020-09-15T08:56` with a `T` between date and time and with two-digit hour of day.

Comment: I don’t know if this is what you are after: `LocalDateTime.parse("2020-09-15T08:56").atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore"))` yields `2020-09-15T16:56+08:00[Asia/Singapore]`.